# Trouble dispaying names with Vector coding

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Good afternoon.....I am currently a student in a C++ course and we are writing code for Vectors. In an assignment we have to display 3 student names. When I add the names after the following code is run it only displays the number of vectors and not the names (as is required). Any assistance is appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    char choice;
    vector <string> studentVector;
    cout << "My Student Vector" << endl;
    while (running == true)
    {
        cout << "Choose a Selection: [A]dd Student, [V]iew Student, [R]emove      Student, [E]xit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        cin.ignore();

        if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Enter Student's Name: ";
            string tempVar;
            getline(cin, tempVar);

            studentVector.push_back(tempVar);
        }
        else if (choice == 'V' || choice == 'v')
        {
            cout << "You have " << studentVector.size() << "Student(s)." << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i << studentVector.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << i << ". " << studentVector.at(i) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
        {
            int pos;
            cout << "Enter the vector position for the student in question: ";
            cin >> pos;
            cin.ignore();

            studentVector.erase(studentVector.begin() + pos);
        }
        else if (choice == 'E' || choice == 'e')
        {
            running = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Selection" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step 1: Indent your code sanely. Use the live preview to verify that the code is readable before you hit submit.

Answer (score 5):

In the `for` loop where you display the names, did you really mean `i << studentVector.size()`?

Comment: This is indeed the problem. Simple typo.

Comment: I guess this is where I'm stuck. The video we watched had that as the loop statement and it worked in the video...not sure what it "should" be. Any other help would be fantastic.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compare those values, but you are not. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B.

Comment: It should be `for (int i = 0; i < studentVector.size(); i++)`.  If the video had `<<` instead of `<` then the video is incorrect.